# Unable to use laptop display since attaching monitor

Tags: display, 15.10

**Manufacturer will be taking this in for repair. Thanks to those that tried to help.**

I recently got a new Skylake laptop with 15.10 installed.

The problem is that since connecting my external monitor, I can't seem to be able to use the laptop's own display.

I've tried using mirrored display, turning on/off the different displays and using the proprietary and open source/Ubuntu drivers.

I've read several posts concerning dual displays here, but none of the solutions I've seen seem to work.

All software is up to date.

Update: xrandr -q shows *DP1*, *HDMI1* and *VIRTUAL1*
HDMI1 is connected. The others aren't and commands like **xrandr -d VIRTUALDISPLAY1** yield *Can't open display [name]*

Comment: what laptop ? brand and model ? what graphic card ? integrated ? which dirver ?

Comment: Apollo from Entroware. You've likely not heard of them. Skylake integrated. I've mentioned the drivers I've used. I've upgraded to Intel's latest 15.10 release. It seems clear that this is a hardware issue, as I've done a full reinstallation of 15.10 and it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by using the Fn+F5 command or maybe yours may be Alt+Comman+F5 since it's a Mac. Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything.

Fn+F5 just brings up the function helper/super key menu. Alt+Ctrl+F5 takes me to a full screen command line and other things involving F5 do a refresh of some kind.  

I'm not on a Mac.

Comment: The function key+F5 and F6 adjust the brightness. That didn't help, unfortunately; the laptop hasn't has its brightness set too low.

Comment: There's a command to set display from your laptop to the screen. Try a combination of Fn+FX

Comment: I tried them all. Sadly, no dice. Fn+F7 cycles through all displays; result: monitor, desktop on monitor and blank screens all around.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like that Ubuntu on that Laptop is stuck in the external display mode.

- When you power it down and power it on again without the external display detected, does anything show up on the internal display ? You should see, in sequence: BIOS - Grub - Linux boot - Login screen
- When you have it up and running on the external display and go to system settings - displays. Does the laptop display is shown ? Can you enable and use the laptop display ?

Comment: Nothing shows up at all, unfortunately. The same goes for switching off or unplugging the external display while it's up and running fully.  

I can go to the display options and activate the laptop display, or mirror it. But neither allows me to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unplugging the battery or even unplugging and plugging bask in the display connector inside the laptop? I have had similar issues with laptops in the past while running ubuntu, and those seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks, but the manufacturer has decided that this is a hardware issue and it will be repaired or replaced.